# Dropdown in form with document library names

Tags: 2013, document-library, custom-list, custom-form

I have a custom list with a custom **New Form** in which I would like to have a drop down box that lists all the names of the document libraries in the site.

Is this possible and how should I go about achieving this?

Comment: How do you develop that custom "New Form"? I mean using Info Path or ASP.NET or Javascript+ HTLM

Comment: It's the standard (Create/Edit/Disp)Form that you have for a Custom List.